# The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). How to find the value of a series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like

```
found_record
    Unnamed: 0                          AID         AnotherID                      otherID PositionType    CreatedVer     LatestVer DeleteFlag
194        162  00000000000000010601233000119682  129030_503520  00000000000020010601233000119678            2  000190010111  000190010111          0
```

and I do

```
found_record['PositionType']
194    2
Name: PositionType, dtype: object
```

This is a Series

I want to compare the position type of this record to a number (for example 2)

but when I do

```
if found_record['PositionType']==2:
(Pdb) n
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How can I compare it?

p.s. I tried

```
condition(found_record['PositionType']==2)
*** Non-numeric breakpoint number (found_record['PositionType']==2)
```

Comment: Check explanation after *The alternatives mentioned in the Exception are more suited if you encountered it when doing if or while.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have 2 steps to extract the value and compare it to a number:

1. extract the value of the pandas cell. As a dataframe is a 2D animal (2 axes: index and columns), you need a double dereferencement. If you are sure of the index value, you can do simply

   ```
    found_record[194, 'PositionType']  # should be 2, or maybe the string '2'
   ```

   if unsure, you can just extract the first value of the Series:

   ```
    found_record['PositionType'].iloc[0]  # id. 2 or '2'
   ```
2. convert the retrieved object to a number (here an integer) because you already know that the Series has not an integer dtype (you showed it is `object`)

   ```
    int(found_record['PositionType'].iloc[0])   # will be 2
   ```